reference sample section of the measurement part in Stim
I am very interested in the reference sample section of the measurement part in Stim, so I looked up the relevant code in Stim and displayed the relevant content in class. stim in Stim/doc/python'apy_reference-vDev.md Still in Circuit In Circuit.referenc_Sample, but I did not find any related classes in src/stim/circuit/circuit.cc. Instead, I found relevant descriptions in src/stim/simulators/tableau_Simulator.inl. Where else can I learn more about this part?

Stim is written in C++ and uses pybind11 to expose methods to Python. Stim uses a simple rule for identifying files related to pybind: they're the ones with ".pybind." in the filename. So you shouldn't be starting in src/stim/circuit/circuit.cc you should be starting in src/stim/circuit/circuit.pybind.cc.
In my experience the easiest way to find the pybind declaration of a method is to search for the name of that method with quotes around it in files with pybind in the name. For example, if you search for "reference_sample" you find:
    c.def(
        "reference_sample",
        [](const Circuit &self, bool bit_packed) {
            auto ref = TableauSimulator<MAX_BITWORD_WIDTH>::reference_sample_circuit(self);
            simd_bits_range_ref<MAX_BITWORD_WIDTH> reference_sample(ref.ptr_simd, ref.num_simd_words);
            size_t num_measure = self.count_measurements();
            return simd_bits_to_numpy(reference_sample, num_measure, bit_packed);
        },
        pybind11::kw_only(),
        pybind11::arg("bit_packed") = false,
        clean_doc_string(R"DOC(
            @signature def reference_sample(self, *, bit_packed: bool = False) -> np.ndarray:
            Samples the given circuit in a deterministic fashion.

            ...

which is in fact the call creating the python method.
Finding these entry points is key. If you have a C++ IDE like clion or visual studio you can then keep using go-to-definition to explore the code.

thanks  for your answer,I will go take a look immediately
